# json Data Output in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I am using the ASP.NET command

```
var returnValue = new JsonResult { Data = items.Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize) };

return returnValue;
```

to return the paged contents of a table via JSON, but when I got to try to parse it, in jQuery, the `$.each` takes each character as an individual element.

The output from that is along the lines of

```
[{"ItemNumber":1,"Description":"Description1"}, {"ItemNumber":2,"Description":"Description2"}]
```

listing all the rows and fields correctly.  However this doesn't look like correctly formatted JSON to me (I beleive it should be encased in `{}`), is it?

If not what should I be doing to correctly output the table? If so, how can I loop round each element in jQuery, and extract the field values?

Comment: If you're looking for a good place for ASP.NET/jQuery reference information, check out http://encosia.com/, specifically http://encosia.com/2008/03/27/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correctly formatted JSON.

You could try evaluating it with

```
var someVar = eval(jsonValue);
```

but this may lead to XSS.

Or even use this [plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/).

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059207/getting-invalid-string-around-my-json-outputted-from-using-the-javascriptseri/1059250#1059250) may be related too.

Comment: $.getJSON sorted it out.  Are there any known issues with using that (I thought I had read somewhere someone saying not to use it)?

Comment: No, since I believe this method sanitizes your response before parsing it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, using `eval` might be dangerous: unlike the case when it's enclosed in {}, it's possible to subvert the construction of an array. This occurs when `eval` tries to create an array using the `Array` constructor. See [this post](http://ejohn.org/blog/re-securing-json/).

If you're not worried about that, you can use `eval` - for safety, the JQuery plugin in wtaniguchi's answer.

Comment: Yeah, I personally never use eval to evaluate JS. I won't how safe json evaluation methods didn't get to jQuery core.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not loop through like this?

```
for (i = 0; i <= returnValue.length - 1; i++){
   //access your properties like this:
   returnValue[i].ItemNumber;
   returnValue[i].Description;
}
```

I don't know if using JsonResult will work like that, but if you return a list of objects in your server side code, it will work like that.  Assuming you're using Asp.Net AJAX it will serialize automatically.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there exists also the following json deserializer in Asp.net Ajax:

```
Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.deserialize(...)
```

You'd have to browse for the exact usage since I don't know it by heard now.

Answer (score 0):

I use the AJAX.NET function **Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.deserialize** to get my JSON data when I've created it using **System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize**.